# Apache Server can't turn off (EnterpriseDB Installation with Stack Builder)

Tags: apache

I know it seems to be an odd question.

I have downloaded and installed PostgreSQL 9.3 from its main website, then I used Application Stack Builder to install ODBC, JDBC, Apache/PHP v2.2.22, phpPgAdmin v5.1.

Now the problem for me is I am used to use programs like MAMP (where you can exit the program and kill the server at the same time), or in an IDE (like MyEclipse's included Tomcat or Jetty), or in a framework like Play's built-in JBoss Netty server. Those servers, since they are connected to an IDE, or program, or framework, they can be easily turned off; and I am used to turn off a server when I am not using it.

I find out I can't turn off this apache server installed by Application Stack Builder. I tried terminal commands. It does not work. Whenever I type in localhost:8080, the welcome page will just pop out.

Do I need to turn it off? How do I do so? Also, can I turn of PostgreSQL database server as well? (Like in MAMP, you always have the option to turn Apache and MySQL server off)

Added: I'm using Mac OS X.

Comment: what OS do you using?

Comment: It's not really "PostgreSQL's", it's the EnterpriseDB StackBuilder. I suggest asking them about this on their forums, as they really should offer a convenient way to start/stop installed services and control autostart. I'd suggest looking in the services control panel (Windows) or at the launchd configuration (mac).

Comment: On my Windows 8 service is called "EnterpriseDB ApachePHP"

Comment: Yeah..I'm using Mac OS though. It is EnterpriseDB's problem. Now the servers (both database server and PHP server) are always on. I worry about my computer's battery life or any security hazard.

Answer (score 1):

To restart EnterpriseDB Apache, I did

```
sudo /Library/PostgreSQL/EnterpriseDB-ApachePHP/apache/bin/apachectl graceful
```

Explanation:

On my machine this exact problem was because the apachectl was still default Mac OS X.  This can be verified by doing

```
which apachectl
```

To which I got the response:

```
/usr/sbin/apachectl
```

This is the default apache in Mac OS X, not the Enterprise DB one.  I did not want to mess with system paths so I left this one alone. You can also create aliases to if you bounce apache often.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I did?
I just unsinstalled EnterpriseDB-ApachePHP  and any other PostgreSQL you might have on your Mac.
Reboot your Mac and try it again.
 Once you have setup Jenkins and everything is running great, you can install EnterpriseDB again if you need. Patrick K.02/8/2017

Comment: Uninstall PostgreSQL is hardly the solution!